# GlassFish regional settings - JPQL query ORDER BY

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

My JPQL query contains ORDER BY on column which contains national characters (polish). On test machine ordering is ok, but when I deploy to production names with polish characters are at the end of the list.

Both machines use the same Glassfish version and connect to the same remote db (oracle 11).
The difference is testing machine has Windows XP Polish, JDK 7u3 32bit, production has Windows 2008 Server English, JDK 7u3 64bit.

I suppose Java uses language from OS and this affects db connection.
How can I change regional settings that Glassfish use?

Comment: have you tried changing the regional settings on windows (English) to Polish? What do you observe?

Comment: Regional settings are set to Polish, dosen't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting jvm paramters in your startup file like so:

`java -Duser.language=pl -Duser.region=PL .....`